# Try catching a variable passed in from res.render

Tags: javascript, try-catch, ejs

I am executing a try catch block within a script tag on my ejs webpage.

My server renders the page sometimes with the token & user, and sometimes without. Each time I passed through a variable I would do the `var x = <%- JSON.stringify(x) %>;`. This time I did it, since there was nothing passed in, it gave me an error.

This is not the issue. The issue I am running into is that it does not seem to work! See the below code:

```
try {
            var Token = <%- JSON.stringify(Token) %>;
            var User = <%- JSON.stringify(User) %>;
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("there is no token/user");
        }
```

I want for my code to try to initlize these variables, if they were passed in from the res.render function from the server. If they were not passed in, no problem, just continue on.

Comment: that will produce a syntax error if either of those are not defined. you can't try/catch a syntax error.

Comment: You will need to put the `try/catch` in the serverside code, and still emit valid clientside code.

Comment: @Bergi Perhaps that would be the better way to do it. 
For now, I basically have it so if I don't get a user/token back, it splits into two different res.render functions. One which includes the two, and one which doesn't.

Comment: Sure you can emit code that does that, but still you need to handle the server-side errors on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `try/catch` to detect a syntax error.

Instead, you could give a default value in case the variables aren't set.

```
var Token = <%- JSON.stringify(Token || "") %>;
var User = <%- JSON.stringify(User || "") %>;
if (Token == "" || User == "") {
  console.log("there is no token/user");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tokenexist = false;
var userexist = false;


 <% if (Token) {
    tokenexist = true;

}
if (User) {
    userexist = true;
} %>


if (userexist && tokenexist) {
    var Token = '<% - JSON.stringify(Token) %>';
    var User = '<% - JSON.stringify(User) %>';

} else {
    console.log("there is no token/user");

}
```